# Calendar List View that groups like values

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar that I'm using to track employee sick time. I have two fields from which I'm trying to create a new list view. "Employee Name" is a Person or Group field and "Occurrences" is a number field.

I'm trying to create a list view that will only show 1 row for each employee and provide the sum of the Occurrences in the cell next to the employee's name.

I've tried using the Group By setting in the list settings, but this does not give me the truly desire result. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Totals setting in the list view settings.

1. In Group By section, Group By the column "Employee Name".

[image]

2. In Totals section, choose sum for column "Occurrences".
   [image]

The view would be like this:

[image]